# How to Open report n time in new tab in for loop asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

so i have report i want to open n time in different tab when the user press print .
this is the code :

```
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.open('")
        sb.Append("../rptViewer.aspx?RptPath=" + RptPath + " &RptName=" + rptName)
        sb.Append("');")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), _
                  "script", sb.ToString())
```

i put it inside for each  because i dont now how many time the user want to print it i get the number copies from data base then i loop the number of copies but its only open one tab each time

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

VB.NET is an event driven programming language, it means that we can handle alot of event and *do stuff* when these event occur

For example we can create a function that will be executed every time that the user press a key:

```
Private Sub Main_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

End Sub
```

Now we have to handle what key the user press, because the function will be fired on every key press! It isn't really difficult:

```
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.PrintScreen Then
        'Do some stuff
    End If
```

So at the end we come up with this little function:

```
Private Sub Main_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.PrintScreen Then
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.open('")
        sb.Append("../rptViewer.aspx?RptPath=" + RptPath + " &RptName=" + rptName)
        sb.Append("');")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), _
              "script", sb.ToString()) 
    End If
End Sub
```

---

***Remarks:***

I suggest to put your code inside a `Sub()` in orther to improve readability of the code, as shown below:

```
Private Sub this_is_an_awesome_name()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.open('")
    sb.Append("../rptViewer.aspx?RptPath=" + RptPath + " &RptName=" + rptName)
    sb.Append("');")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), _
          "script", sb.ToString()) 
End Sub
```

And now call it inside the event handler function:

```
Private Sub Main_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.PrintScreen Then
        this_is_an_awesome_name()
    End If
End Sub
```

Usually is better to avoid declaring a large snippet of code inside an event handler function, like a `button.click` or `KeyPress` events. It's a good habit that improves code readability and helps alot during debugging sessions.

---

If anything isn't clear, feel ***free to ask*** in the comment below!

Comment: My Main Problem is its only open one new time even when loop three time

Comment: If you implement the event handler function that I shown above there will be any loop

Comment: @aaa The event handler function is always listening for a keypress, it's like it is in a forever loop but it doesn't waste resources and it doesn't stress the cpu like a forever loop. Also it doesn't block the program execution until the user press a key ;)